# (TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object) for inversion counter using merge sort

Tags: python

I am trying to do a recursive call to counter the number of inversion of a list of numbers

for example: `[3,1,2,4]` The two inversions are `(3,1)` and `(3,2)`.

So the algorithm should return 2.

I tried this using the merge_sort method.

```
def merge(x,y,last_inversion_sum):
    x_length = len(x)
    y_length = len(y)
    n = x_length+y_length
    i=j=0
    inversion = 0
    merged_list = []
    while i<x_length and j <y_length:
        if x[i]>y[j]:
            merged_list.append(y[j])
            j+=1
        else:
            merged_list.append(x[i])
            i+=1
            inversion+=1

    if i == x_length:
        merged_list.extend(y[j:])
    else:

        merged_list.extend(x[i:])

    inversion = inversion+last_inversion_sum
    return merged_list,inversion


def compute_inversion(a):
    array_length = len(a)
    if array_length<=1: return 0

    L,inversion1 = compute_inversion(a[:int(array_length / 2)])
    R,inversion2 = compute_inversion(a[int(array_length / 2):])
    inversion_sum = inversion1+inversion2

    return merge(L,R,inversion_sum)

lizt = [3,2,1,5]

_,inversion_num = compute_inversion(lizt)
print(inversion_num)
```

Error popped up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/A.LXR/inversion.py", line 40, in <module>
    _,inversion_num = compute_inversion(lizt)
  File "D:/A.LXR/inversion.py", line 32, in compute_inversion
    L,inversion1 = compute_inversion(a[:int(array_length / 2)])
  File "D:/A.LXR/inversion.py", line 32, in compute_inversion
    L,inversion1 = compute_inversion(a[:int(array_length / 2)])
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Where did it go wrong?
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: you return an `int` object, not a tuple, when `array_legnth <= 1`, hence, when you unpack that, you get that error

Comment: why did you call compute_inversion function inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compute_inversion(a) function should always return the same kind of values, a list and an int, even when array_length<=1:

You could do it like this:

```
def compute_inversion(a):
    array_length = len(a)
    if array_length<=1: return a, 0

    L,inversion1 = compute_inversion(a[:int(array_length / 2)])
    R,inversion2 = compute_inversion(a[int(array_length / 2):])
    inversion_sum = inversion1+inversion2

    return merge(L,R,inversion_sum)
```

It works now and result is :

```
3
```